# how i will come to know my server is working in cs go

Tags: counter-strike-global-offensive

By updating **740 validating** some type of installation goes on and after it gets completed I created a text file with extension .cmd which i saw from this link

**( that information is given below startup)**.
When i clicked on the file **classic casual**, some type of working (itself) goes on a black page and in the end **vac secured** i s written.After that i started playing cs go and by browsing server i never came to know that is my server working and. pls help me...

Comment: This question has bad grammar, incorrect punctuation, and random bold text that is not neccessary. The video could have been replaced by a simple link, and your question isn't clear in general.

Answer (score 1):

Try to manually connect to your server by typing:

```
connect <ip>:<port>
```

in cs:go console.

Things You should check:

- do you have an external IP
- is your port is open ?